# Android google map keep crashing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code in companydetails.java and every time it's crashed

```
 case R.id.textView:
           if (!((String) this.companyMap.get("latitude")).equals("") || !
 ((String) this.companyMap.get("longitude")).equals("")) {
               intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("latitude", Double.parseDouble((String) 
   this.companyMap.get("latitude")));
               intent.putExtra("longitude", Double.parseDouble((String) 
           this.companyMap.get("longitude")));
               intent.putExtra("company", (String) 
                this.companyMap.get("company"));
               break;
           }
```

And I got these errors

Device Log

```
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : Process: com.mra.tnow, PID: 9186
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "28°23′50"
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at com.marwan.tabuknow.CompanyDetails.onClick(CompanyDetails.java:368)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
00:43:49 E AndroidRuntime : at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to parse a `String` in the format `"28°23′50"` to a `Double` and that will be not possible.

1. One solution is to save your coordinates as (e.g. latitude=32.82108, longitude=-16.975873)
2. Or use your coordinates but without parsing the values to `Double`.

Comment: now i get this error 05:34:22 E AndroidRuntime : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mar.tnow/com.mar.tnow.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse 28°23'50 to a double.
Pass this parameter as string or convert to a WGS-84 coordinate which is a double.
It depends of your requirements.